# URL Regex match for Istio- VirtualService throwing 404

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

My Gateway and VirtualService for the sample BookInfo looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE 
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: "v1"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

I am terminating TLS at the gateway and in the HTTP route, I have configured a regex match on "v1" for HTTP and routing it the productpage service.

I am testing this by sending a request to `http://External-IP/api/v1/products` (the sample application's productpage service is configured to return a text body on this endpoint), but the request fails with HTTP 404. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the mistake here, the `regex : "v1"` does not do partial match.

```
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: v1
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

Instead I had to specify `regex : .*v1.*` to make it work. I am able to route now.

```
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: .*v1.*
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, unless I'm reading this wrong your path filters dont match your request, your request is `/api` and your filters dont have that

Comment: No, look at the second match criteria, I am using regex with v1, is that not supposed to match "api/v1/products" ?

Comment: i didnt notice that one, but `v1` would not work as well